# Problems Installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

My pc has 2gb of ram.. By mistake I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit) 
Can I install it on pc with 2 gb of ram and it has intel dual core processor.

Comment: You can try it with a LiveUSB, and 2GB of ram is enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully installed a 64-bit version, then your CPU is 64-bit.
There is no problem at all.

But a 32-bit version may perform better on old Intel CPUs in some cases. Also it will consume less RAM.

***But if everything works well, there is no need to re-install!***